# Datagram Sockets works on machine not over internet

Tags: java, sockets, datagram

I am trying to send Datagram Sockets over the internet. These programs work on the local machine when the XXXXXX is replaced with localhost. it does not work when placed on different machines and different web connections. Has anyone encountered this before? I have set up port forwarding for the router and it still does not work. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class UDPServer
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
       {
        System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack" , "true");
          DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(9876);
             byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
             byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
             while(true)
                {  
                   System.out.println(" I am waiting to recieve something.");
                   DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);

                   serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
                   System.out.println("I recieved something");                  
                   String sentence = new String( receivePacket.getData());
                   System.out.println("RECEIVED: " + sentence);
                                   //serverSocket.send(sendPacket);
                }
       }
} 

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class UDPClient
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
       BufferedReader inFromUser =
          new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
       DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
       InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("XXXXXXXXXX");
       byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
        //byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
       String sentence = inFromUser.readLine();
        System.out.println(sentence);
       sendData = sentence.getBytes();

       DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, 9876);
       clientSocket.send(sendPacket);

       clientSocket.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Talk to your ISP. It isn't a programming issue.

Comment: Everything looks good. You need to make sure you are port forwarding correctly and your local firewall allows java through it

Comment: Thanks How do I ensure my firewall allows java through it? I have windows 10 and a netgear router.